# Populate POJO from XML using VTD-XML

Tags: java, xpath, vtd-xml

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Report>
        <Node>
            <Detail>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <Value>Value 1</Value>
                <Tag1>
                    <Owner>
                        <Id>
                            <INT>12345</INT>
                        </Id>
                    </Owner>
                </Tag1>
            </Detail>
            <Status>
                <Result>Pass</Result>
            </Status>
        </Node>
        <Node>
            <Detail>
                <Id>2</Id>
                <Value>Value 2</Value>
                <Tag1>
                    <Owner>
                        <Id>
                            <String>TEST</String>
                        </Id>
                    </Owner>
                </Tag1>
            </Detail>
            <Status>
                <Result>Fail</Result>
            </Status>
        </Node> 
        <Node>
            <Detail>
                <Id>3</Id>
                <Value>Value 3</Value>
                <Tag1>
                    <Owner>
                        <Id>
                            <UN>UNKNOWN</UN>
                        </Id>
                    </Owner>
                </Tag1>
            </Detail>
            <Status>
                <Result>Waiting</Result>
            </Status>
        </Node>
    </Report>
</Document>
```

Based on above structure, I want to read elements / attributes and populate POJO (XPath preferably) as element path is not consistent, e.g.: `<Tag1>`.

I'm not able to figure out how to proceed. I've tried using AutoPilot but it reads data sequentially, e.g. all Node Ids. I can't figure out a way to read all data within `<Node>` and then proceed to next one and so on. At the end I need to return populated POJO collection.

DOM is out of scope as XML file is huge, almost 800MB to 1GB in size with approx. 600,000+ `<Node>`.

Thanks in advance.

**XML Reader**

public void process(final String fullPath) {

```
try {
    final VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();

    if (vg.parseFile(fullPath, false)) {
        final VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        final AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath(ROOT);

        while ((ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
            final AutoPilot pilot1 = new AutoPilot(vn);
            pilot1.selectXPath(ROOT + "/Detail/Id");

            while (pilot1.evalXPath() != -1) {
                final int t = vn.getText();
                if (t != -1) {
                    System.out.println(vn.toNormalizedString(t));
                }

                final AutoPilot pilot2 = new AutoPilot(vn);
                pilot2.selectXPath(ROOT + "/Status/Result");

                if (pilot2.evalXPath() != -1) {
                    final int k = vn.getText();
                    if (k != -1) {
                        System.out.println(vn.toNormalizedString(k));
                    }
                }
                // pilot2.resetXPath();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception) {
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your pojo and some code example as to how you would like to proceed? Autopilot can do random access at ease which is the point of vtd... it will jump from node to node...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author I've included code. I tried various options but don't have copy of all. POJO is plain bean to hold parsed data

Comment: I think you are trying to nested iteration, I will do an example that you can adapt to your situation...

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit to make it work... plus correcting a few things... will come back with more comments embedding in the code....

A few things to keep in mind

1. **never put autoPIlot instantiation and xpath selection in a while
   loop. Never!**
2. Reuse by resetXPath()
3. Use push and pop to maintain the consistent state in the outermost while loop.

import com.ximpleware.*;
public class sawi {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();

    if (vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\sawi.xml", false)) {
        final VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        final AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/Document/Report/Node");
        final AutoPilot pilot1 = new AutoPilot(vn);
        pilot1.selectXPath("Detail/Id");
        final AutoPilot pilot2 = new AutoPilot(vn);
        pilot2.selectXPath("Status/Result");
        while ((ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
            vn.push();
            while (pilot1.evalXPath() != -1) {
                final int t = vn.getText();
                if (t != -1) {
                    System.out.println(vn.toNormalizedString(t));
                }

            } 
            vn.pop();
            vn.push();
                if (pilot2.evalXPath() != -1) {
                    final int k = vn.getText();
                    if (k != -1) {
                        System.out.println(vn.toNormalizedString(k));
                    }
                }
            vn.pop();
            pilot2.resetXPath();
            pilot1.resetXPath();

           // vn.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for sample code. I'll check and let you know.